# How to use 2 cookies for auth?

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core

I have 2 devices, pc and a special tablet. I want to have with same app .net core 2.0 2 cookies, or cookies scheme with 2 auth cookies, because for pc I want to expire in 5 minutes and for that special tablet to not expire at all. How to do that. Now I have this...

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "myScheme",
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300),
                CookiePath = "/",
                CookieSecure = env.IsDevelopment() ? CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest : CookieSecurePolicy.Always
            });
```

I think I could use UseWhen method or I don't know...

Or to sign in on different cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Check [Using cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                    {
                        options.LoginPath = "/auth";
                        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookiebuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.1
                        options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
                        {
                            Name = "CustomCookie",
                            HttpOnly = false
                        };
                    });
}

public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
     app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work for dotnet 2.1.3, that code is obsolete

Comment: what specific part doesn't work? does the code compile? Please note you would have to use **`await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), 
    authProperties);`** to sign in a user. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#tabpanel_CeZOj-G++Q-1_aspnetcore2x